# Split a Linestring with Delimiters

Tags: string, split, plpgsql

I have a database with many coordinates in binary form like 
"0102000020E610000004000000CEB0074955792B40D7C9CFFC208249406999FB9A9B792B4053550D6723824940E89E1AD4237A2B40A1B0D52F228249402DE86278917A2B4047C1F80E23824940"

I use St_AsText to convert this in a LineString.
I get something like

"Linestring((3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220))"

I need to split this LineString WITH Delimiters in a hole PL/pgSQL-Function.
My first Split would have the delimiter','.

The result would be

3.584731 60.739211
3.590472 60.738030
3.592740 60.736220

My second delimiter is the '  ' so i can get every single Point. I know its stupid but it need to be done this way. Its a testproject for my company university. 
Now i can calculate with the points like 3.590472*60.738030+3.592740 -60.736220 and so on.

My Problem is to put this hole Process in a PL/pgSQL Function because i have really big problems with the syntax of the language. If somebody could write a example function i will be really thankfull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to develop new function - PostgreSQL has nice function - `string_to_array(string, delimiter)`

```
postgres=> select string_to_array('1.0 2.0 3.2', ' ');
 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {1.0,2.0,3.2}
(1 row)

postgres=> select * from  unnest(string_to_array('1.0 2.0 3.2', ' '));
 unnest 
--------
 1.0
 2.0
 3.2
(3 rows)
```

Parsing strings in plpgsql is wrong idea - some operations over longer strings will be slow probably. And it is not necessary. Postgres has parsing functions to array, xml, json and (when it is necessary) you can use a [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html).

```
postgres=> select * from regexp_split_to_table('1.0 2.0   3.3', e'\\s+');
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 1.0
 2.0
 3.3
(3 rows)

postgres=> select v[1] from regexp_matches('1.0 2.0   3.3', '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+','g') r(v);
  v  
-----
 1.0
 2.0
 3.3
(3 rows)
```

Some simple split string implementation in PL/pgSQL:

```
postgres=# \sf split_string 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.split_string(text, text)
RETURNS SETOF text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
  pos int; 
  delim_length int := length($2);
BEGIN
  WHILE $1 <> ''
  LOOP
    pos := strpos($1, $2);
    IF pos > 0 THEN
      RETURN NEXT substring($1 FROM 1 FOR pos - 1);
      $1 := substring($1 FROM pos + delim_length);
    ELSE
      RETURN NEXT $1;
      EXIT;
    END IF; 
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$function$

postgres=# select * from split_string('AHOJ NAZDAR BAZAR',' ');
 split_string 
--------------
 AHOJ
 NAZDAR
 BAZAR
(3 rows)
```

Comment: At first thank you!. I know that is a bad idea but its a test and we want to compare a PL/pgSQL-Function with a extern C-Function. So i need the PL/pgSQL-Function :(

Comment: I updated my reply - but again - it is wrong usage of plpgsql, and wrong benchmark.

Comment: You are my BadAss-Hero :)))

Comment: How do you wold do a benchmark with PL/pgSQL and a extern C-Function?

Comment: you have to choose a procedure that can be normally implemented in PLpgSQL in your work. Artificial benchmarks can be really confusing. Example: I implemented a quick sort in plpgsql. For large arrays it is 1000x slower than C internal quick sort implementation. What is benefit of this benchmark. Absolute zero. Nobody with good mind will be use plpgsql functions for sorting. PLpgSQL is perfect glue for SQL operations - because bottle neck is SQL operations. The speed is comparable with PHP. But for intensive numeric (string)operations operations anybody should to use PLPython or PLPerl or C.